# Add tag synonyms: [updates] & [updated] -> [update] on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms, synonym-request

Could:

- [updates](/questions/tagged/updates) 105 questions
- [updated](/questions/tagged/updated) 9 questions
- [updating](/questions/tagged/updating) 72 questions

be synonyms of:

- [update](/questions/tagged/update) 2990 questions

**Update:** All of the [tags] now have the same, quite reasonable tag excerpt.

Comment: I always prefer the plural or collective, so I'd prefer to see `updates` be the master.  The tag wiki can be moved over.  It probably has more questions due to being older.  Either way, good suggestion.

Comment: What about the [tag:updating] tag? Shouldn't that be a synonym, too? (And in that case, I might prefer that *this* be the master tag.)

Comment: Good catch @Cody.  I tend to favor the shortest.  But that said, I don't mind which is chosen -- just want to clean up the tagging!  :O)